# Android 4.4 Status Bar With Same Color of ActionBar

Tags: android, xml

I've a folder named 'values-v19' with a 'styles.xml' file. This file contain:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

And the app looks like:

[image]

How do I get the status bar with the same color as the ActionBar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library. It does exactly what you need.